# Remove duplicates from array, preserving some values

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have a PHP array like this:

```
[0] => Array ( [0] => type [1] => value1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => type [1] => value2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => type [1] => value3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => id [1] => value4 ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => id [1] => value5 ) 
[5] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => value6 ) 
[6] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => value7 ) 
[7] => Array ( [0] => division [1] => value8 ) 
[8] => Array ( [0] => division [1] => value9 ) 
[9] => Array ( [0] => division [1] => value10 )
```

and I need to change it to this:

```
[0] => Array ( [0] => type [1] => value1,value2,value3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => id [1] => value4,value5 )
[5] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => value6,value7 ) 
[7] => Array ( [0] => division [1] => value8, value9, value10 )
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Yes, there is. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Oops sorry, i tried  array_unique() function but then the "values" are lost. Then i tried array_unique() again serializing all elements, that too failed. Should i create new array to do this ??

Comment: This ultimately will be a fairly basic loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` and an inner `switch`

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1)
{
    switch ($arr1[0])
    {
        case 'type':$type.=$arr1[1].",";break;
        case 'id':$id.=$arr1[1].",";break;
        case 'name':$name.=$arr1[1].",";break;
        case 'division':$division.=$arr1[1].",";break;
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [type] => value1,value2,value3
    [id] => value4,value5
    [name] => value6,value7
    [division] => value8,value9,value10
)
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/125138)